Do replicate weight, when the are available, supersede all the design-based procedures and analysis?
If the agency that conducted a survey and releases micro data at the individual or household level also supplies replicate weights for that sample, do these weights completely supercede any need or use for traditional design base measures such as strata, clusters, imputation of non-response items and post survey raking to force the sample to match demographic totals from, typically, the last census? Is the usual practice to calculate both design-based estimates and replicate weight estimates, as a check on one another? Or is it more usual to use only the replicate weights, when these are available?

See Lumley's answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629981/when-to-use-replicate-weights-in-complex-survey-analysis
